# ionic, how to use anchor element with an ID as the href target

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

In page I have to use anchor element, but on click it jump to home page.

example html code:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div>
      <ul>
       <li>
         <a href="#html-syntax">sample</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div  id="html-syntax">
       <div class="col">sample</div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

how to jump `id="html-syntax"` when click '`sample`'?

Comment: Use Ionic's `$ionScrollDelegate.anchorScroll(id)` not tried it but seems like the place to go. This link is on their forum which might help https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-navigate-to-particular-id-using-href-of-a-tag/6538/5

Comment: Thank you very much for your add comment, help me Solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Look, I was working with this item and I found this solution.

Look, this is your div anchor:

```
<div id="myAnchor"></div>
```

This is your item. Any element.

```
<img (click)="gotoAnchor()">
```

Finally, you set the function:

```
gotoAnchor() {
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code there should work, honestly. If you have an anchor element with an ID as the href target, and you also have an element with that same ID on the page, then (most browsers) should jump to the appropriate element.

You just need to make sure you've nested all your elements properly, since if you don't then you can get unexpected behaviour like page loads or jumping to the top.

```
<a href="#html-syntax">sample</a>

<div id="html-syntax"></div>
```

Also make sure you don't have target="_blank" in your anchor tag, as this will try to open a new window. As well, any events you've subscribed to on the anchor tag will still fire off like normal.

Comment: make sure all elements properly, page can jump to the appropriate element. but join to ionic framework, it jump to home page。 it url `http://localhost:8100/#/#html-syntax`

Comment: Oh ionic is a framework? Does this help (there's an example codepen in article that is supposedly in ionic)?
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-navigate-to-particular-id-using-href-of-a-tag/6538/8